# how to pass an image as paramenter to sql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, blob

I am a quality analysts and I got a task to test a database function n_execute() which takes 3 parameters 
1. image_name
2. image_data (byte array) this is a blob type.
3. data_created
Now my problem is that to test this function I want to call this function but don't know how to input iamge o the second parameter of this function.
I know we can do it by writing some java code which calls this function but I primarily wants to execute it through SQL editor only.

Comment: When you are looking for an image format which is easy to represent in ASCII, then SVG might be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which database platform you are working with but in a SQL Server T/SQL script [IMAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187993.aspx) data would be a [binary constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx). A simple example would be `0x0102030405` which represents 5 hex bytes; 01, 02, 03, 04 and 05.

**Edit for PostgreSQL**

For PostgreSQL take a look at the docs, [Binary data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html). Note;

> The bytea type supports two external formats for input and output:
>   PostgreSQL's historical "escape" format, and "hex" format.

The PostgreSQL equivalent to my SQL Server example would be `E'\\x0102030405'`.

Comment: I am  using postgreSQL